# needle-point size white spots all around the outer edge of Ficus leaves

Tags: trees, leaves, ficus

Hello. I am writing from the San Fernando Valley, in Southern California where the temperatures vary from 48F at night to 85F during the day this time of the year.  I have a 35 year old Ficus outside in my patio in a large pot. Its physical spot hasn't changed in the past 20 years.  About two years ago it was affected with the White Fly disease. It almost lost all of its leaves :(   I treated it with "Bayer Advanced Tree & Shrub Protect & Feed" and thank god it came back :).  However, in the past month,  it has been losing an unusual number of leaves again.  These are older leaves as well as brand new baby leaves.   I figured this time, I won't wait till the tree is almost bare before I ask for help!

I have noticed that there are needle-point size white spots all around the outer edge of the most newer leaves...  I also found one leaf that had lots and lots of white scars on it.   Please see attached pictures.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Detailed instructions for adding  photographs are at this link on our sister site: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer

Comment: Photo would be very useful - but do the white spots come off if you touch or rub them? Are they standing proud of the leaf, or within the tissue of the leaf?

Comment: Hi! Are you still having trouble adding pictures? If so, leave a comment and we'll help you. Good answers are hard when we can't see the problem. If you answer Bamboo's questions, that would be great. Without more specifics, your question is in danger of being put on hold. That's described on [this page](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) in our [help]. If that happens, you still have time to add your details. We're glad you're here, and hope we can work together to save your tree!